# CachedAnonymousMethodDelegate1 in code disassembled from reflector

Tags: porting, reflector

I'm exploring the possibility of porting silverlight's System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations to the desktop in order to reuse validation done in my silverlight business objects (don't ask...).

The problem is I'm getting code like...

```
// Methods
protected ValidationAttribute() : this(CS$<>9__CachedAnonymousMethodDelegate1)
{
    if (CS$<>9__CachedAnonymousMethodDelegate1 == null)
    {
        CS$<>9__CachedAnonymousMethodDelegate1 = new Func<string>(null, (IntPtr) <.ctor>b__0);
    }
}

protected ValidationAttribute(Func<string> errorMessageAccessor)
{
    this._syncLock = new object();
    this._errorMessageResourceAccessor = errorMessageAccessor;
}

protected ValidationAttribute(string errorMessage) : this(new Func<string>(class2, (IntPtr) this.<.ctor>b__2))
{
}
```

Is there anyway that I can work around this?

Answer (score 0):

This is the way an anonymous delegate looks like, after compilation.

You could change the anonymous delegate in the source to be a declared delegate.

Then it should be no problem to reverse engineer it with a reflector like tool.